# Force download with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mootools

I have a php file like this:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"my-data.csv\"");

$data = stripcslashes($_REQUEST['data']);
echo $data; 

?>
```

I can post (proper formatted) data to it and it will return a csv file. I do that like this:

```
    var data = $('table').toCSV('tbody > tr');
    $('table').addEvent('click', function(){            
        new Request({
                url: 'getCSV.php',
                method: 'post'                  
        }).send('data=' + data);            
    });
```

In Firebug I can see the request works and the response is ok. But the Download dialog does not pop up; how to fix that? Do I need different headers in the PHP file?

Comment: Ajax cannot force a download dialog. It will simply download the content of the file you are trying to serve. When using Ajax, you are better off storing the file and then returning the URL of the file so you can use `window.location` to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the JS to this:

```
    var data = $('lijst').toCSV('tbody > tr');

    var form    = new Element('form', {method: 'post', action : 'getCSV.php'});
    var field   = new Element('input', {type: 'hidden', name: 'data', value: data});
    var submit  = new Element('input', {'type' : 'submit', 'value' : 'Download'});
    form.adopt(field,submit);

    form.inject($('lijst').getElement('caption'));
```

Which adds a nice download button to the table and as the browser follows a form submit, the download dialog pops up. Thanks for thinking with me.

Answer (score 1):

As Gavin said, ajax calls cannot force download, and response is simply saved into a variable.
You must create a hidden form and POST data. Like this:

```
var data = $('table').toCSV('tbody > tr');

$('table').on('click', function(){            
    $('<form action="getCSV.php" target="_new" method="POST" style="display: none;">'+
        '<textarea name="data">'+data+'</textarea>'+
      '</form>')
    .appendTo('body')
    .submit();          
});
```

P.S I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to utilize an iframe. So when clicking the "download" button you inject the iframe in the page. After you can clean it up.

```
document.body.inject(
 new Element('iframe', {
    'src': 'http://url.to.download', 
    'style': {
        'display': 'none'
     }
 })
);
```